# Laravel Nested foreach loop from self related model to display in tree style

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I have a category model that related to itself. One category may have more than one subcategory. Each category may be subcategory and also be parent.

In blade, I would like to show in hierarchy or tree. But I have no idea how can I check and display if there is child on each category. I loop using foreach but I really can't think for sub loop. Is it possible to display as follows.

```
 1. Electronic
     1.1 Entertainment
         1.1.1 TV
          1.1.2 DVD
             1.1.2.x there may be more or not
2.Fashion
 2.1 Man
     2.1.1 Top
     2.1.2 Bottom
```

Comment: Post your code. [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/etrepat/baum I'd recommend you use it instead

Answer (score 0):

Create relations on your model. You can make self relation like

```
public function childs(){
  return $this->hasMany('Category', 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```

And can access to the childs as `Category::with('childs')`
In view u can make something like:

```
@foreach($categories as $c)
  {{$c->title}}
@if($c->childs->count()>0) 
  @foreach($c->childs as $child)
    $child->title
  @endforeach
@endif
@enforeach
```

Comment: `$this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');`? Foreign relation should be `parent_id` and Local `id`.